# how to pass multiple values of a checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following haml code

```
%nav.breadcrumbs
  %h2 Breadcrumbs
  %ol
    %li
      %a{href: data_sources_path} #{t('Defaults.Home')}
    %li
      %a
    %li
      %em #{t('Registrations.new.AccessRequest')}
%br
%h3#content-header1.content-header #{t('Registrations.new.Header')}
%section.form
  %form.standard{action: registrations_path, method: 'post'}
    %fieldset{"aria-labelledby" => "content-header"}
      %input{type: 'hidden', name: 'authenticity_token', value: form_authenticity_token.to_s}  
      %legend  
      %ul
        %li    
          %label 
            #{t('Registrations.new.CheckBoxHeader')}
            %abbr.required{title: "Required"} *
        - Role::ROLES.each do |role| 
          %input#roles{name: "access", type: "checkbox",value:"#{role}"}/
          %label{for: "roles"} #{role}            
    %fieldset.input-actions
      %legend Actions
      %input.primary-action{name: "invoke", type: "submit", value: t('Buttons.Send')}/
      %input.cancel{name: "invoke", type: "submit", value: t('Buttons.Cancel')}/
```

here suppose my roles are admin and editable... I can successfully display the roles as checkbox and also params[:access] gives me the particular role i have selected. Suppose i select both the roles params[:access] just returns back admin. I want to get both the roles. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a simple trick to make rails see "access" as an array

```
%input#roles{name: "access[]", type: "checkbox",value:"#{role}"}/
```

That way params[:access] will be an array on which you can loop over